# Check my solution to $x^2 + x + 1 > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I spent an hour or so yesterday trying to solve the inequality $x^2 + x + 1 > 0$. Since I'd spent so long on a problem didn't seem like it should be that difficult, I decided I'd call it a day and try it again later.

I just had another look at it and this solution became immediately obvious:

$$x^2 + x + 1 > 0 \ \ \forall \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I'd justify this by stating that $x^2 > x \ \ \forall \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}$. Because of this, even if $x < 0$, the right hand side of the inequality will always be positive. Am I correct?

Comment: actually $x^2 < x $ for $0 <x <1$.

Comment: Your claim is false $(1/2)^2< 1/2$.

Comment: Didn't think about that ..

Comment: It is true that $x^2 + x + 1 > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ but not for the resons you give. If $0 < x < 1,$ we have $x^2 < x.$

Answer (score 15):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ 4\:f(x)\: =\: 4\:(x^2+x+1)\ =\ (2x+1)^2 + 3\: \ge\: 3\ $ thus $\rm\:f(x)\ge 3/4$

More generally one can decide polynomial  (in)equations by partitioning the real line into intervals based on the *finite* number of roots, and testing on each interval. Here there are no real roots, so it has constant sign, so has the sign of $\rm\:f(0) = 1.\:$

This is a special case of Collin's [cylindrical algebraic decomposition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%20dubuque%20tarski%20cad&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=e50b7ed8b228eb18&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1682&bih=1460) algorithm, an effective form of Tarski-Seidenberg quantifier elimination for the reals. For deep generalizations, search on "semialgebraic geometry" and "o-minimal".

Comment: Is there any special significance in choosing to multiply by 4 and add 3, or is this just a case that works out?

Comment: @James It's a convenient way to *complete the square*, just as in the classical quadratic formula.

Answer (score 9):

$$x^2 + x + 1 > 0 \Leftrightarrow x^2 + x + \frac{1}{4} > -1 + \frac{1}{4} \Leftrightarrow (x+\frac{1}{2})^2 > -\frac{3}{4} $$ And we have the desired result by the positivity of the square. (i.e. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2 \geq 0$)

Answer (score 4):

First I will show that with small modifications, your approach can be made to work. (It is, however, simpler to use one of the methods in other answers.)  At the end, I suggest an additional simple approach.

It is clear that $x^2+x+1 \ge 1$ if $x \ge 0$. There is potential trouble only when $x<$, so suppose that $x<0$.
Because it is all too easy to make errors when handling negative numbers, let $w=-x$. Then $x^2+x+1=w^2-w+1$, and $w$ is positive.

If $w \ge 1$ (that is, if $x\le -1$), then $w^2 \ge w$, so $w^2 -w+1\ge 0$. (Here we used the method that you proposed.)

That method doesn't work when $0<w<1$, for then $w^2<w$.  But $w^2>0$ and $w<1$, so $w^2-w>-1$, and therefore $w^2-w+1>0$.

**Another way:** Note that $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=x^3-1$, and that $x-1$ and $x^3-1$ are positive if and only if $x>1$, and are negative if and only if $x<1$.

If $x>1$, then $x-1$ and $x^3-1$ are both positive, so the ratio $\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}$, that is, $x^2+x+1$, is positive.

If $x-1$ and $x^3-1$ are both negative, then again their ratio $x^2+x+1$ is positive.

And finally if $x=1$, then $x^2+x+1$ is positive.

Note that in exactly the same way, we can show that $x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots +x+1$ is always positive if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

There's also this answer (but I'm not sure if it qualifies as a proof):
[image: Plot of $y=x^2+x+1$, notice it never touches the $x$-axis]

This is a plot of $y=x^2+x+1$, notice it never touches the $x$-axis.

Comment: It may be good to add some words to this chart to show how it solves the problem.

Comment: Graphing your data is a good way to get started to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I bring x and 1 to the other side to change the problem to $x^2 > -1 - x$.

Note that $x^2$ is always positive for real $x$, so the equality can only be false when $x < -1$.

But, if $x < -1$, $x^2$ is still positive, and so is $- x$. So we need to prove that when $x > 1$, then $x^2 > x - 1$ holds. But since $x^2 > x$ when $x > 1$ this holds.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to solve this (actually a different approach):

Since $1^2+1+1=3>0$ any y for which $y^2+y+1 \leq 0$ holds would yield a root of the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+x+1$ by the intermediate value theorem. Therefore you get a second root (besides $1$) of the polynomial $q(x)=p(x)(x-1)=x^3-1$. But this is a monotonically increasing function and hence has at most one zero.